# Any libraries that can make accessing Google APIs as a service account simpler for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, oauth-2.0, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

**Background:**  My idea is to create a primarily content-heavy website (think news articles or blog posts) written entirely in nodejs.  Since creating content on Google Drive (Google Docs) in particular is very simple, what I would like to do is have Nodejs retrieve the website's content from Google Docs.

**Challenge:** As far as I can tell, the correct way to do this according to Google is to create a [Service Account](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2?hl=es-#Service_Accounts) so that the application can access the files stored on Google Drive without requiring user-intervention in the form of a confirmation.  Google provides three libraries--java, python, and php--for server-to-server requests.  Does anyone know of anything similar already written by the Node community?  I am aware of [node-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) but I've searched through it's source and haven't found anything referencing private keys, which are required for server-to-server interaction, which I'm taking to mean it's not supported.  Writing one is also an option, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.  Looking at the Google-written Java Oauth2 client library makes it pretty clear that it's not an easy task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is one library I've found that looks pretty thorough and complete for creating JSON Web Tokens: [JWCrypto](https://github.com/mozilla/jwcrypto)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but in the event others arrive here looking for an answer:
Google is working on an official module to access all of their API's.  Its alpha so be careful but it looks very nice- [github repository](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/)